# How to check if value is contained in array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you check if an array contains a value, for example whether or not "hello" is in the array.

```
  var Greetings = ["hello", "hey", "hi", "sup"];
```

How would I structure the If statement to check the array. I had previously wrote

```
  if ("hello" == Greetings[]) { // greeting
  //runs succsessfully
  }
```

This of course does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Don't understand what you're asking for? 
Do you want to check if a value/string is in the array?

Comment: @IsraGab yes i need to check if the user input contains any of the values in the Greetings array

Comment: If so, I think @NiettheDarkAbsol gave you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NiettheDarkAbsol gave exactly what i was looking for.

I used the indexOf() in my code to get it working the way i was looking for.

```
    if (Greetings.indexOf(messageArray[0]) != -1) { // greeting
    kline.speakAloud("Hello");
    kline.speakText("Hello.");
}
```

the indexOf gives out a negative 1 integer if the input is not in the array. any of the strings in my array work to run this statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

jQuery offers $.inArray, which is functionally equivalent to Array#indexOf.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are obvious duplicates.

Comment: @JaredSmith Who is my question duplicating? if it is a duplicate i would love to know and will gladly use that to answer my question.

Comment: @tecksup I wrote that comment *after* Xufox flagged this as a dupe. Duplicate flags always contain a link to the question this one is suspected to be a duplicate of. See comments on your question. And the fact that your question was answered by a 9 character comment should clue you to the fact that you ***should have done a simple google search or two before posting here and cluttering the site.***